# In tig, is there a way to view diff for all files like Github pull request

Tags: tig

In tig, when showing diff view, we can only view diff per commits. What I want to achieve is a way to view diff for all files (just like `git diff` or Github Pull Request diff view). Is there a way or a mode to do that?
 Example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z197m.png

Comment: You mean selecting multiple commits, not multiple files, so you can look at the total diff of a branch, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what you mean `all files`. diff view is already a pager for `git diff`. 
If you want to increase chunk context, just press `]` or set it in `.tigrc` like

```
set diff-context = 300 # Number of lines to show around diff changes (diff)
```